# GenericObjectPool threshold

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpool

The GenericObjectPool is configured for 12 Threads. Once 12 threads are exhausted, I find the caller thread goes zombie. I think default behaviour is to enqueue extra requests and serve once available instead of killing caller thread.

```
private ImplClass implObject;

for (Iterator iter = anArrayList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {

    //Gets a GenericObjectPool Object
    implObject = (ImplClass) this.getImplPool().borrowObject();

    some code

}
```

I have tried both configurations as below for configuring pool. For me blocking is fine so long as it resumes from borrow statement and process lines below it inside loop.

```
 <bean id="ImplPool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref local="ImplFactory"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>12</value>
    </constructor-arg>    
</bean> 



<bean id="ImplPool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref local="ImplFactory"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>12</value>
    </constructor-arg>    
<constructor-arg>
         <bean id="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_BLOCK" 
         class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean" />
    </constructor-arg>      
<constructor-arg>
        <value>-1</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Can you please suggest a config for  a blocking GenericObjectPool on reaching threshold ?

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: I think your second configuration is OK. What do you mean by `caller thread goes zombie`? How do you check the thread status?

Comment: I corrected this. problem was I was not returning Objects to pool. I later made a dedicated THread to return objects to poool as released and this resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my setup was OK. Only Object was not being returned to pool due to which threads were not being created again.